# How to map object with custom class property that returns object with null property values instead of returning null using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I have these classes

```
public class SemModel
{
    public int SemId {get; set}
    public string AreaId {get; set}
    public string Longitude {get; set}
    public string Latitude {get; set}
}

public class SemDto 
{
    public int SemId {get; set}
    public AreaDto Area {get; set}
}

public class AreaDto 
{
    public string AreaId {get; set}
    public string Longitude {get; set}
    public string Latitude {get; set}
}
```

I want to be able to map SemModel to SemDto wherein if AreaId, Longitude and Latitude are null SemDto.Area is instatiated with AreaId, Longitude and Latitude properties having null value.

Actual output is that I have a SemDto where Area property is null

this is the mapping I have

```
CreateMap<SemModel, SemDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Area, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new AreaDto
             {
                 AreaId = src.AreaId,
                 Longitude = src.Longitude,
                 Latitude = src.Latitude
             }));
```

Given:

```
new SemModel(){SemId =1, AreaId =null, Longitude=null, Latitude=null}
```

Expected Output:

```
new SemDto(){SemId = 1, Area = new Area(){ AreaId =null, Longitude =null, Latitude =null}}
```

Actual Output:

```
new SemDto(){SemId = 1, Area = null}
```

Another Attempt 1

```
.ForPath(dest => dest.Area.AreaId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AreaId))
.ForPath(dest => dest.Area.Longitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Longitude))
.ForPath(dest => dest.Area.Latitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Latitude));
```

Still no luck. Welp!

Comment: ResolveUsing allows for a method containing conditions to be applied to your mapping: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing

Comment: Not sure how this helps

Comment: Try `ForPath` for each of those properties instead of your resolver.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu updated my question to try yung suggestion. no luck

Comment: I know this isn't always an option depending on your use case, however, have you considered changing the pattern you use to create these objects? You could possibly use a shared interface or base class along with a single method that will return one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cfg.CreateMap<SemDto, SemModel>().IncludeMembers(s=>s.Area).ReverseMap();
    cfg.CreateMap<AreaDto, SemModel>().ForMember(d=>d.SemId, o=>o.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

It uses [unflattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html). `ForPath` works too.